# getting error while exporting mongodb using mongo cmd in windows

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I am trying to export mongodb database using this command:

```
mongoexport -d db_name
```

But I am getting this error:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:15

What will be the command to export db?

Comment: did you ran that command directly from the system command line? check [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) docs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mongodump` it's faster:

```
mongodump -d <database_name> -o <directory_backup>
```

And to `restore/import` that, i used (from directory_backup/dump/):

```
mongorestore -d <database_name> <directory_backup>
```